# click on a button, show a div, reduce opacity of all except div, close div and return all things to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

it seems to be a big problem for me!
i have a **div** that i click on a button this div is shown and opacity of all elements in **body** area is reduced.
but i want when close this div, all elements return to former [css](/questions/tagged/css) attributes.
i used this [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) code but i don't know how to return former [css](/questions/tagged/css) attributes:
(example: before click on *showDiv* some elements opacity was 0.9 and other is 1 but when click on *hideDiv* all elements opacity is 1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showDiv").click(function(){
        $("#main").find("*").css("opacity","0.5").off('click'),
        $(".div").css({"display":"block","opacity":"1"});
    });
    $(".hideDiv").click(function(){
        $("#main").find("*").css("opacity","1"),
        $(".div").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to define a css class with the opacity set in it.  Then you can addClass() removeClass() it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery just to toggle a class on an element, then set properties with and without that class. E.g:

```
$(".showDiv").click(function(){
    $("#main").addClass("active");
});
$(".hideDiv").click(function(){
    $("#main").removeClass("active");
});
```

Then in your css:

```
#main * {
   opacity: 0.5;
}

#main.active * {
    opacity: 1;
}

#main .someChild {
   opacity: 0;
}

#main.active .someChild {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```